# ZUUL Pre-Filter Use Case (Pre-Filter App Authorization)

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I would like to leverage a ZUUL pre-filter to interrogate a request, pull a header value out of the request, check another endpoint or property file, and compare the two.  And if there is a gap, redirect the request and not allow it to continue, or if ok allow it to continue.  Seems like a perfect use case.  I'm not concerned with headers being tampered with, we have TLS throughout the application and trust between the calling application and ZUUL.

Comment: I don't see a question.

Comment: Maybe it's an obvious use case, i just know there are specific points in time of a request where make changes or doing things with it can be problematic.  Like grabbing headers, and making decisions on them,  Decisions that would ultimately result in a redict etc...make sense?